“dial tcp : I/O timeout” during the load test execution in K6 running in AKS, but works okay while running it local
So, here is my teardown while running the k6 load test in AKS (0% — ✓ 0 / ✗ 816  ):
 time="2024-04-24T14:41:13Z" level=warning msg="Request Failed" error="Get \"stackoverflow.com": dial: i/o timeout"                                                                                     
│      ✗ status was 200                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    ││       ↳  0% — ✓ 0 / ✗ 816                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ││                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          │
│      █ teardown                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ││                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          ││      checks.....................: 0.00%   ✓ 0         ✗ 816                                                                                                                                                                                              │
│      data_received..............: 1.6 MB  48 kB/s                                                                                                                                                                                                        ││      data_sent..................: 231 kB  6.8 kB/s                                                                                                                                                                                                       ││      http_req_blocked...........: avg=0s      min=0s    med=0s       max=0s       p(90)=0s       p(95)=0s                                                                                                                                                │
│      http_req_connecting........: avg=216.9ms min=0s    med=210.35ms max=701.97ms p(90)=398.33ms p(95)=414.23ms                                                                                                                                          ││      http_req_duration..........: avg=0s      min=0s    med=0s       max=0s       p(90)=0s       p(95)=0s                                                                                                                                                ││      http_req_failed............: 100.00% ✓ 816       ✗ 0                                                                                                                                                                                                │
│      http_req_receiving.........: avg=0s      min=0s    med=0s       max=0s       p(90)=0s       p(95)=0s                                                                                                                                                ││      http_req_sending...........: avg=0s      min=0s    med=0s       max=0s       p(90)=0s       p(95)=0s                                                                                                                                                ││      http_req_tls_handshaking...: avg=0s      min=0s    med=0s       max=0s       p(90)=0s       p(95)=0s                                                                                                                                                │
│      http_req_waiting...........: avg=0s      min=0s    med=0s       max=0s       p(90)=0s       p(95)=0s                                                                                                                                                ││      http_reqs..................: 816     24.147861/s                                                                                                                                                                                                    │
│      iteration_duration.........: avg=8.06s   min=181µs med=3.51s    max=33.77s   p(90)=31.8s    p(95)=32.51s                                                                                                                                            ││      iterations.................: 817     24.177454/s                                                                                                                                                                                                    ││      vus........................: 20      min=0       max=816                                                                                                                                                                                            │
│      vus_max....................: 817     min=497     max=817

And these are the results when I run it locally or from a Virtual Machine (60% is expected):
     ✗ status was 200
      ↳  60% — ✓ 494 / ✗ 322

     █ teardown

     checks.........................: 60.53% ✓ 494       ✗ 322
     data_received..................: 3.4 MB 147 kB/s
     data_sent......................: 445 kB 19 kB/s
     http_req_blocked...............: avg=153.53ms min=0s      med=180.87ms max=479.19ms p(90)=329.17ms p(95)=368.01ms
     http_req_connecting............: avg=56.34ms  min=0s      med=75.68ms  max=251.28ms p(90)=109.12ms p(95)=139.23ms
     http_req_duration..............: avg=436.52ms min=0s      med=94.29ms  max=11.08s   p(90)=320.28ms p(95)=1.7s
       { expected_response:true }...: avg=590.06ms min=70.08ms med=102.54ms max=11.08s   p(90)=1.52s    p(95)=2.36s
     http_req_failed................: 29.16% ✓ 322       ✗ 782
     http_req_receiving.............: avg=3.54ms   min=0s      med=0s       max=100.25ms p(90)=6.26ms   p(95)=25.16ms
     http_req_sending...............: avg=706.85µs min=0s      med=0s       max=27.67ms  p(90)=1.02ms   p(95)=1.59ms
     http_req_tls_handshaking.......: avg=94.59ms  min=0s      med=97.8ms   max=325.25ms p(90)=208.27ms p(95)=233.84ms
     http_req_waiting...............: avg=432.27ms min=0s      med=92.43ms  max=11.08s   p(90)=318.61ms p(95)=1.7s
     http_reqs......................: 1104   47.678398/s
     iteration_duration.............: avg=5.47s    min=1.07ms  med=1.71s    max=23.1s    p(90)=22.21s   p(95)=22.57s
     iterations.....................: 817    35.283742/s
     vus............................: 16     min=16      max=775
     vus_max........................: 817    min=817     max=817


running (0m23.2s), 000/817 VUs, 817 complete and 0 interrupted iterations
contacts ✓ [======================================] 817 VUs  23.2s/30s  817/817 iters, 1 per VU

Why is that? Am I missing a rule or something in my AKS cluster?

Okay, I deleted the peering and added this to my test.js, load test is running ok now.
export const options = {
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true,
};

